# How to keep different sessions' datas in a page with php

Tags: php, html, session

I'm trying to keep datas for every sessions. You'll understand when you see the code and screenshots.

```css
<?php
require('connect.php');

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
  echo "Your session is running " . $_SESSION['email'];
  echo "</br></br>";
}
$a=$_SESSION['email'];
$sql = "SELECT title, content FROM post";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Posted by: $a </br> Title: " . $row["title"]. " </br> Content: " . $row["content"]. "</br></br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="post.php" method="post">
You can add new content or <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></br></br>
Your Email:</br>
<input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="email"/></br></br>
Title:</br>
<input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="title"/></br></br>
Content:</br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" required autocomplete="off" name="content">
</textarea></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body></html>
```

When I'm logging in with mertonar@gmail.com. It looks like that;
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWx2U.png)

but when i'm logging in with a@a. It looks like that;
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4vAJ.png)

I want to keep every content for each sessions. When i enter something with mertonar@gmail.com and after logging out from this session. I want to see "Posted by : mertonar@gmail.com" (I mean, with email which written that content) 
 with other sessions too. I do not see my current session mail everytime. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `post.php` you should save the emailaddress also in your `posts` table.

Your query wil be something like this: `"SELECT title, content, email FROM post"`.

The output will be: `echo "Posted by: " . $row["email"] . "</br> Title: " . $row["title"]. " </br> Content: " . $row["content"]. "</br></br>"`;

Comment: Omg, i asked totally wrong thing.. Sorry. I meant how can i add session email to database ? Don't mind to email form in the screenshots then how can i see the email?